# How to make ISO8601 produce Hebrew day of the year, week of the year?

Tags: calendar, hebrew, iso8601, date-arithmetic

Can someone think of a way to calculate the Day-of-the-Year and Week-of-the-Year for the Hebrew calendar?  I'm using ISO 8601 which can return the Hebrew year, month, day of the month and day of the week.  I'm trying to write re-usable code to calculator any Torah portion (Parsha).

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one who finds this impossible!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [hebcal](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal) command to do this. There are also ports for [JavaScript](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-js) (shameless plug, it was written by me), [Java](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-java), and [Perl](https://github.com/hebcal/hebcal-perl).

Answer (score 1):

This is easy if you can use Java. My library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) enables the features you want (in [Hebrew calendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HebrewCalendar.html)):

```
PlainDate iso8601 = Iso8601Format.parseDate("2018-03-16");
HebrewCalendar hc = iso8601.transform(HebrewCalendar.axis());

int hyear = hc.getYear();
HebrewMonth hmonth = hc.getMonth(); // obtains an enum
int hdayOfMonth = hc.getDayOfMonth();
Weekday hdayOfWeek = hc.getDayOfWeek(); // obtains an enum
int hdayOfYear = hc.getDayOfYear();

int weekOfYear =
    hc.get(
        CommonElements.weekOfYear(
            HebrewCalendar.axis(),
            HebrewCalendar.getDefaultWeekmodel()
        )
    );

System.out.println("year=" + hyear); // 5778
System.out.println("month=" + hmonth); // ADAR_II (technical result, see next line)
System.out.println(
    "month=" + hmonth.getDisplayName(Locale.ENGLISH, hc.isLeapYear())); // Adar

System.out.println("day-of-month=" + hdayOfMonth); // 29
System.out.println("day-of-week=" + hdayOfWeek); // FRIDAY
System.out.println("day-of-year=" + hdayOfYear); // 207
System.out.println("week-of-year=" + weekOfYear); // 30
```

There are many more features, for example taking into account start of day in the evening of previous day (including astronomical calculations of sunset) or hebrew biblical clock time or different numbering schemes for months etc.